# What is the listener of Fragment for FragmentTransaction.detach()?

Tags: android

I need to let a fragment knows it is detached by `FragmentTransaction.detach()`, and as https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/QlkLMsncDwg says, the `onDetach()` of Fragment class will not do this.

Is there another working listener, or I need to make another interface for it?
Thanks.